# Getting all the child elements of a parent div

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the IDs and Classes of all children elements in a parent DIV.

I've tried the following:

**The HTML**

```js
var children = [].slice.call(document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('*'), 0);
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = children.join('\</br>');
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="A"></div>
  <div id="B"></div>
  <div id="C"></div>
  <div class="D"></div>
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

But the output is:

```
[object HTMLDivElement]
[object HTMLDivElement]
[object HTMLDivElement]
[object HTMLDivElement]
```

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong here please?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v47nngyo/)

Comment: I rather don't. I am still learining JS

Comment: What is your expected output? Is it `["A", "B", "C", "D"]` ?

Comment: hello @nem, yes that's what I need.

Comment: If You want to get list only children elements with id or class, avoiding elements without id/class, You can use `document.getElementById('container').querySelectorAll('[id],[class]');` ... `querySelectorAll('[id],[class]')` will "grab" only elements with id and/or class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you would want this...

```js
var children = [].slice.call(document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('*'),0);

var elemnts = new Array(children.length);
var arrayLength = children.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var name = children[i].getAttribute("id")||children[i].getAttribute("class");    
    elemnts[i]=name;
}
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = elemnts.join('\</br>');
```

```html
<div id = "container">
    <div id = "A"></div>
    <div id = "B"></div>
    <div id = "C"></div> 
    <div class = "D"></div>  
</div>
<div id = "output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Jesus Angula, getAttribute was missing in my code. thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I'd be grateful if you mark this entry as the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to achieve this using minimal changes to your code. Mainly, you are missing some sort of a method to extract ids/classes from your results. For example, here is how to do it using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
// build children
var children = [].slice.call(document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('*'),0);
// build ids and classes
var idsAndClasses = children.map(function(child) {
   return JSON.stringify({ id: child.id, classes: child.classList });
});
// output ids and classes
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = idsAndClasses.join('\</br>');
```

```html
<div id = "container">
    <div id = "A"></div>
    <div id = "B"></div>
    <div id = "C"></div> 
    <div class = "D"></div>  
</div>
<div id = "output"></div>
```

OUTPUT:

```
{"id":"A","classes":{}}
{"id":"B","classes":{}}
{"id":"C","classes":{}}
{"id":"","classes":{"0":"D"}}
```

Comment: Thanks @nem. JSON.stringify is new for me. will take a look into it!

Comment: No problem. If its not obvious from all the different answers, there are many ways to achieve what you want so try things out and use the way that best works for you. Let me know if you need any further help

Answer (score 2):

A good ressource is [MDN ParentNode.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children).

No need to `hack` array function like `[].slice.call` or other things, only simple JS and DOM access.
Easy and simple.

When you have an HTMLElement you can access directly to the properties or attributes you want by:
 - `myElement.id` to get the id
 - `myElement.className` to get the all the classes

And this is exactly what you have wen you call `children`, an HTMLCollection !

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output') 

var father = document.getElementById("container");
var sons = father.children;

var len = sons.length;
var i = 0;

for(i ; i < len ; i++){  
   var child = sons[i];
  
   // we access directly to the attributes
  //                                    +----------------------
  //                                    v                     v
   output.innerHTML += '<div>' + child.id + ' : ' + child.className + '</div>';
   
   // do what you want / need with them.
   var toShow = child.id + '' + child.className;
   output.innerHTML += '<div>' + toShow + '</div>'
  
  
   output.innerHTML += '<div>---</div>'
  
  
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="A"></div>
  <div id="B"></div>
  <div id="C"></div>
  <div class="D"></div>
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: thanks @Anonymous0day for pointing out how to access the properties directly!

Comment: You're welcome !  it is so simple by this way, don't forget you can look for what you need here https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/Reference/API

Answer (score 1):

**Set up our HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="A"></div>
    <div id="B"></div>
    <div id="C"></div>
    <div class="D"></div>
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

**Target our children:**

```
var children = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('*');
```

**Then loop over each child element and output to the page:**

```
[].forEach.call(children, function (child) {
        if(child.id){
            document.write(child.id + "<br>");
        } else if(child.className) {
            document.write(child.className + "<br>");
        } else {
            document.write("this element has no class or id <br>");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @SkullDev this helped a lot!

Comment: No problem! would you mind marking my answer as correct? :)

Comment: Also, do you understand the code or do you need more explaining done? :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your comments.
Based on your examples and suggestions, I produced the following.
it works except for the classnames.

```
var children = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('*');

var arr =[];
for (i = 0; i < children.length-1; i++){
    if(children[i].id){
        arr.push(children[i].getAttribute("id"));
    } else if (children[i].className){
        arr.push(children[i].getAttribute("class"));
    }
}

  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = arr;
```